# Bemis toilet has a removable plastic container

Tags: toilet

Toilet won’t fill. I can lift out the container. If I remove it will the toilet fill and flush correctly?

Comment: Can you include a picture? Isthe container in the tank? Have you tried turning the fill valve? They are usually on the wall behind the toilet or on the floor.

Comment: If the removable plastic container has been in there from day one, removing it without replacing/repairing/reseating is not likely going to be the proper solution. However, far more details (including the pics asked for by @DAS) and any details you may have that lead up to this situation will go a long way toward getting you a good solution.

Comment: Our toilet has a plastic container which is part of the water saving design.  But having it or not wouldn't make it not fill. I agree, we need more details...does it run and never stop?